# Mocked Method is throwing NullPointerException in Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, jpa, nullpointerexception, mockito

This is my test class

```
     @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
     public class ServiceTest extends Service{


    @Mock
    EntityManager eman = Mockito.mock(EntityManager.class);
    @Mock
    Query query;

    @InjectMocks
    private Service service;


   private static final String NAME = "name";


  @Before
  public void setUp() {

     this.service=new Service();

       }


   @Test
   public void firstMethodTest() {


     Query query = mock(Query.class);   
    when(
            eman.createNamedQuery(NAME)).thenReturn(query);

    when
        (  query.setParameter("name", Type)).thenReturn(query);

    when (query.getSingleResult()).thenReturn(type);

    **service.getAllMethod(1, "string");**


        assertSame(/*Something to compare */);

    }
}
```

This is my Service Class method

```
    public  getAllMethod(int ID, String string)
         {


        Query query=em
                .createNamedQuery("name");

        **query.setParameter("string", Type);**
         type= query.getSingleResult();


}
```

When **service.getAllMethod(1, "String")** is invoked from Mocked Object ,I am getting NPE at **query.setParameter("name", Type)** because I think query is still NULL. Kindly Assume that My Service is working fine.
Thanks in Advance

While debugging I check the value of **Query query** in service class.Its value is null.Cant figure out how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are recreating your Service before every test.  So the `Service` that Mockito is injecting the mocks into has been lost.

Get rid of the `setUp` method and, instead, declare service like this:

```
@InjectMocks
private Service service = new Service();
```

There are some other things wrong too. e.g. The `EntityManager` `Mockito.mock` isn't required, the test class shouldn't be extending `Service`, the `@Mock Query` isn't being used.

---

Here's a rough template to start with:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestA {

    @Mock
    EntityManager eman;

    @InjectMocks
    private Service service = new Service();

    @Test
    public void firstMethodTest() {
        Query query = Mockito.mock(Query.class);
        Mockito.when(eman.createNamedQuery(NAME)).thenReturn(query);

        service.getAllMethod(1, "string");
    }
}
```

Assuming Service is something like:

```
public class Service {
    @Autowired
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public void getAllMethod(int i, String s) {
        Query q = entityManager.createNamedQuery("name");
        ...   q isn't null here for me
    }
}
```

Comment: I did the changes as suggested by @Mr Spoon. Yet same result.

Comment: I've edited answer: try that as a starting point for your test.

Comment: Btw, @Mr Spoon, with `@InjectMocks`, Mockito will automatically initialize those variables via the `@RunWith` annotation or `MockitoAnnotations#initMocks()`

Comment: I tried with the above suggestions ,still I am getting same error. :(

Does it has anything to do with my Serivce Class which is annotated @Statless ?
 or Is there something more to add in any of the XML's.